# read CSV apostrophe

Tags: ruby, csv, apostrophe

I am trying to read a CSV and Ruby stops reading once it encounters an arrow in CSV. The arrow is supposed to be apostrophe. I can't replace it in CSV because when I copy and paste, I paste a space.

I tried to use CSV.foreach or File.open, then read each_line. Both methods have the same problem.

The character is SUB in black in text editor.

How shall I solve this problem?

```
CSV.foreach(filename) do |row|
 puts row
end

File.open(filename, "r") do |f|
 f.each_line do |row|       
     puts row
 end
end
```

[image]

Comment: This is an encoding issue. You need to understand, what the original file encoding is and then explicitly set this encoding when loading this file into CSV.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the CSV somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file isn't encoded the way Ruby expects by default, you need to specify the encoding manually when you call `foreach`, which would look like this:

```
CSV.foreach(filename, encoding: Encoding::UTF_8)
```

If you're not sure how the file is encoded, you can use [`String#encode`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-encode) as a pretty heavy hammer to clean it out, though you'll lose some characters in the process.

```
File.read(filename).encode(
  Encoding::UTF_8,
  undef: :replace,
  invalid: :replace,
  replace: '' 
)
```

This says if the character is undefined or invalid, replace it, and replace it with an empty string. Of course, you can tweak options to get the result you'd like.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. CSV.foreach(filename, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8')

Comment: i will try to replace the undefined characters because after ruby processes it, I will use another software (STATA) to analysis the data, which has the same problem to handle these characters.